# How to save a PDF which is directly viewed in Firefox into Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, firefox, pdf, firefox-extensions

I am looking for a possibility to directly save/send a PDF which is opened in Firefox into Google Drive. The solution should work without having the Google Drive client installed on the computer.

Are you aware of any solution other than downloading the PDF first and re-uploading it again through the Google Drive web interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Append the URL of the web hosted PDF file or Office document to "url" querystring of Google Docs Viewer service](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2016/10/how-to-save-online-pdf-office-docs.html) -

```
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://aka.ms/SQLtoAzure/MobPDF
```

In the example above the URL https://aka.ms/SQLtoAzure/MobPDF points to a PDF file. Any URL with a .PDF extension would work too. After that file is opened within the browser, click the "Save to Drive" icon (as shown in the screenshot) in the header of Google Docs Viewer to save it to your Google Drive.

Similarly the [Office Apps Online Viewer can be used to save any Office document hosted on the web to OneDrive](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2016/01/office-apps-online-viewer-can-display.html).

Answer (score 2):

Going off of [mvark's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/99942/206539), you can use the following bookmarklet for quick access.

```
javascript:(function()%7Blocation.href%20%3D%20'https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fviewer%3Furl%3D'%20%2B%20location.href%7D)()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/MgADSBA2jEc) to a discussion on Google Product Forums that should point you in the right direction.
Some of their suggestions include Gladinet, Memeo Connect, and a work around using a Print dialog to save directly to the drive. Good luck.